# Are there any collections of "autological cycles"? (e.g. calque -> loanword)

Tags: linguistics

I am interested in a natural generalization of autological words: cycles of words that each describe their successor (but not themselves).

e.g. an autological 3-cycle is a set of of words "A", "B", and "C"  such that A describes B, B describes C, and C describes A.

The only example I'm aware of is one I discovered incidentally on Wikipedia: calque -> loanword. That is, [loanword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) is a calque (but not a loanword), while [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) is a loanword (but not a calque).

- Is there an actual term for such a cycle?
- What is the longest known such cycle?
- Are there any collections of such cycles?

Wiki has collections of autological words (e.g. [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_autological_terms) and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_autological_terms)) and a [definition/discussion of paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word), but I've not been able to find any references to cycles.

Comment: Questions on ELU should not contain mulitple questions in one, as this makes it difficult to accept a single definitive answer. You can, of course, ask all three as separate questions with links to show that they are related for context.

Comment: Your questions might be better off on the [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: How about "monosyllabic" -> "long"? Or "tetrasyllabic" -> "hyphenated" -> "thirteen-lettered" (or is that cheating?)

Comment: @psmears Nice!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on Linguistics SE.